# how can I have a function executed in the child component every time I meet a condition in the parent component to show the child component?

Tags: reactjs

I have a child component called `Camera` and I call it within a parent component when a condition is met in the style of:

```
<Camera showCamera = {fieldPhoto} />


 
<!-- component parent -->
  handleTakePictureAsync = ({ uri, fieldphoto }) => {
    setFieldPhoto(null);

  };

    const [fieldPhoto, setFieldPhoto] = useState (null)
    return(
        <View>
         <Camera
            showCamera = {fieldPhoto}
            handleTakePictureAsync={handleTakePictureAsync}

         />
         <Button transparent onPress = {() =>
             setFieldPhoto(true)
         </Button>)
        </View>)
```

In the `child` component I have a method to verify if the permissions to use the camera have been accepted, if they have not been accepted, the dialog should be asked asking to allow the camera to run, as many times until it is accepted.

I don't know how to make the confirmation message appear without loading the rest of the component.

```
<! -- Camera Component -->

  export const Camara = props => {
  const [hasPermission, setHasPermission] = useState(null);
  const [showCamera, setShowCamera] = useState(true);
  const propShowCamera = props.showCamera;

  const checkPermissionsCamera = () => {
    const status = Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA).then(permission => {
      setHasPermission(status.status === "granted");
    });
  };

  return (
    <View>
      {checkPermissionsCamera()}
      {propShowCamera && hasPermission && ( rest of code
      .
      .
      .
```

I want to ensure that the rest of the code of the camera component is not loaded until the camera use permissions have been accepted, and that the message asking to accept permissions appears until they are accepted.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your parent component is passing down prop `showCamera` which determines whether the Camera is shown. Since this is a boolean value, you should set initial values to `false` and not `null`:

```
const Parent = () => {
    handleTakePictureAsync = ({ uri, fieldphoto }) => {
        setFieldPhoto(false)
    }

    const [fieldPhoto, setFieldPhoto] = useState(false)
    return (
        <View>
            <Camera
                showCamera={fieldPhoto}
                handleTakePictureAsync={handleTakePictureAsync}
            />
            <Button transparent onPress={() => setFieldPhoto(true)}></Button>
        </View>
    )
}
```

In your child component, you should use a `useEffect` hook to run the `checkPermissionsCamera` function - don't call it directly in the render method as this function sets state, which means your component may rerender continuously:

```
    useEffect(() => {
        const checkPermissionsCamera = () => {
            const status = Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA).then(
                permission => {
                    setHasPermission(status.status === 'granted')
                }
            )
        }

        checkPermissionsCamera()
    }, [setHasPermission])

return (
    <View>
    // Don't do this:
    // {checkPermissionsCamera()}
    {propShowCamera && hasPermission && ( rest of code...
```

I'm also unclear on why you need two `showCamera` values:

```
const [showCamera, setShowCamera] = useState(true);
const propShowCamera = props.showCamera;
```

Also:

> the dialog should be asked asking to allow the camera to run, as many
>   times until it is accepted

Are you sure this is what you want? A never-ending popup asking for camera permission until the user gives permission for the camera to be used? What if they don't want to give permission? You should probably accept that they don't want to and display a message "You need to give camera permission to use this part of the app".

---

One way to write your camera component could be like this:

```
export const Camara = ({ showCamera }) => {
    const [hasPermission, setHasPermission] = useState(false)

    useEffect(() => {
        const checkPermissionsCamera = () => {
            const status = Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA).then(
                permission => {
                    setHasPermission(status.status === 'granted')
                }
            )
        }

        checkPermissionsCamera()
    }, [setHasPermission])

    return (
        <View>
            {showCamera && hasPermission && <div>Rest of code</div>}
        </View>
    )
}
```

Then you wouldn't bug the user with an infinite loop of popups until they grant camera permission.

But if you need permission to show your camera, why render the `Camera` component in the first place? Would it not be better to handle the permission request in the parent component, then once permission has been granted, render `Camera`?

This would also fit with your requirement:

> I want to ensure that the rest of the code of the camera component is
>   not loaded until the camera use permissions have been accepted

Just don't render the `Camera` at all until permission has been granted.

---

Handling permissions in the parent would look something like this:

```
// Parent
const Parent = () => {
    const handleTakePictureAsync = ({ uri, fieldphoto }) => {
        setIsFieldPhoto(false)
    }

    const [hasCameraPermission, setHasCameraPermission] = useState(false)
    const [isFieldPhoto, setIsFieldPhoto] = useState(false)

    useEffect(() => {
        const requestCameraPermission = () => {
            Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA).then(
                ({ status }) => {
                    setHasCameraPermission(status === 'granted')
                }
            )
        }

        if (!hasCameraPermission && isFieldPhoto) {
            requestCameraPermission()
        }
    }, [setHasCameraPermission, hasCameraPermission, isFieldPhoto])

    return (
        <View>
            {hasCameraPermission && isFieldPhoto && (
                <Camera handleTakePictureAsync={handleTakePictureAsync} />
            )}
            <Button transparent onPress={() => setIsFieldPhoto(true)}></Button>
        </View>
    )
}

// Camera
export const Camara = ({ handleTakePictureAsync }) => {
    return (
        <View>
            <div>Normal camera code</div>
        </View>
    )
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, basically I want all the validations and functionality of the camera with the theme of permissions, be made directly from the camera component.

Comment: the desired behavior is to click on a button and popup appears with the permission confirmation. I want this to happen every time I tap on the button until the user accepts.

Comment: Then see my answer where I said "One way to write your camera component could be like this:". The code is contained within the Camera component.

Comment: Yes, and I really appreciate your help, but useEffect only runs the first time. Then it is never executed again, the permissions dialog is not shown again.

Comment: I hope you can help me genius, I know I will learn a lot if you help me along this waty

Comment: I am trying that every time I tap on the button and if the permissions have not been accepted, the confirmation dialog will be displayed again.

Comment: Yes, so you need to run the function from the `Button`'s `onClick` event, not inside the `useEffect` and not inside the `Camera` component, since your button is not inside the `Camera` component either.

Comment: That's what I want to avoid, I want all the functionality to be contained within camera controler, including permission verification.

Comment: thanks crack. Yes, I would like ALL the camera logic to be inside the camera component. That every time you tap on the button, it is verified if you have permissions to use the camera, if not, then you have to show the alert (the user decides whether to accept or not), if you accept the rest of my code is executed, If it is not accepted, the dialogue is closed. and the next time you tap on the button that occurs in the previous step.

Comment: It's because I want to create a component that I can reuse, just that I import <Camera ../> and everything is done, I want to avoid putting the permissions code every time the camera is used.